# Where the ambient temperature sensor is located on 27" iMacs?

Tags: imac, hardware, temperature

I'm using [iStat Pro](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/status/istatpro.html) Dashboard widget to get live system data of my mid-2010 27" iMac.

Under temperature readings it lists **Ambient**. Where the sensor is approximately located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the manual and take apart guide provided by Apple to Apple Certified Mac Technicians: the ambient temp sensor is attached to the CPU blower (or fan).

Comment: Thanks! I'd love to vote up your answer straight away, but do you have any sources for this?

Comment: My source is the manual and take apart guide provided by apple to apple certified mac technicians.  I am an ACMT.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on iFixit below the page at **Step 8** you will see the **temperature sensor** in **orange**

http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+EMC+2309+and+2374+Teardown/1236/1

EDIT : that's the temperature sensor from the LCD

At **Step 12** they mention the sensors but don't really highlight them.